# Is it possible to simultaneously get the contents of a visual selection into a register and replace all the characters?

Tags: vim

Consider the following text file.

```
Replace and yank this portion Ignore this portion
```

Suppose I have visually selected the part that says `Replace and yank this portion`.

I can take one of the following actions at this point.

1. I can use `y` to yank the contents into a register, but this destroys the visual selection.
2. I can use `rx` to replace each of the characters with an `x`, but this also destroys the visual selection.

**Is it possible to simultaneously put the visual selection into a register and replace each of the characters in the visual selection with an `x`?**

That is, I'm looking for a sequence of commands that result in the selected text being in a register, and each character in the selected text replaced by `x`. I'm not picky about which register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately after posting this question, I realized that all I needed was to be able to re-select the text that was just selected.

A quick Google search led to using [`gv`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Visual_selection) for re-selection.

Thus, the final command sequence to achieve the desired effect is `ygvrx`. This will first yank the sequence into the register, re-select the previous selection, and then replace the characters.

Comment: Alternatively you could save the replacement text in a register (e.g. `let @a="some text"`) then visually select `Replace and yank this portion` and type `"ap`.

Comment: @Sergio, The goal is to not have to retype the text in order to put it into a register.

Answer (score 0):

Visually select the text and press `c` for change. Type the text you want and press `<esc>`. The text that was there before (in this case `Replace and yank this portion`) is now in your `""` register, so you can just hit `p` as soon as you want to paste it.

type `:h reg` to see a list of all registers and what text you have inside them.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because it implies that I have to know a priori how many characters are in the visual selection, so I can input the appropriate number of x's. The desire to *replace each character* implies that the command or set of commands I use is agnostic to the number of characters.

Comment: From your question, this requirement isn't obvious. My solution does replace all the characters, it does not necessarily replace each character with another character, but it does replace all characters with as many characters as you type.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion; I had tried to make it clear with step 2) in the question, but I guess it wasn't explicit enough.